# Debugging JS performance differences between two browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I use some javascript/AJAX heavy websites on my mid-end work laptop, running Fedora Linux and primarily Firefox. Overall, those websites tend to bog down my system overall. In some cases the window manager gets affected, other times everything except the browser is usable. I can reproduce this simply by opening one or more of these websites in Firefox. I'm stuck keeping those sites open during my work day, and my solution has been to RDP to one of my Windows servers and open those sites from there. The same laptop runs these sites better at least, on my colleague's Windows 10 install...

The other day, I discovered that Google Chrome worked a lot faster using these sites under Fedora. But I won't switch browser just because javascript performance is bad. I should be able to solve this...

How would I start finding the bottleneck? I know Firefox on Windows works better, and I know that Chrome on Linux works better than Firefox on Linux. I could narrow it down more by booting a Live-USB system. strace gives too much information. Would comparing the results from the [Firefox profiler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler) under Linux vs Windows (or two Linux distributions) give me enough information?

I'm not too well versed with debugging, with web browsers or with javascript. All I know is that I won't switch OS, would rather not switch browsers, and won't get a better computer for a while. I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: It looks like you are an end-user, right? Not the developer of those websites? I won't expect you'll get anything out of such a debug session if you can't change the code yourself. At best you can attach your findings to the support ticket. Do you have any plugins installed? If so, can you try running without them?

Comment: The web sites are not mine, no. I won't be able to change their code, and I don't really want to either. The only thing I know is that the same browser version runs them "okay" in Firefox/Windows, and "okay" in Chrome/Linux. They are a pain to use in Firefox/Linux. I've ran without plugins and also in safe-mode. There is really no difference at all.

Comment: Ok, I see. The profiler reports might help a developer who is working on the Linux branch of firefox to get something patched but that might take *some* time before that will reach you, assuming there is already bug report. I can not be of much help, sorry.